# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'reducer' (typescript)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to run some sample code from a book and I'm getting an error `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'reducer'` from the `tsc` and I'm not sure why?

```
tsc -v 
// Version 2.1.0-dev.20160726
```

**Then I run  ts-node like so:**

```
ts-node 01-identity-reducer.ts
```

**01-identify-reducer.ts:**

```
interface Action {
  type: string;
  payload?: any;
}

interface Reducer<T> {
  (state: T, action: Action): T;
}

let reducer: Reducer<number> = (state: number, action: Action) => {
  return state;
};

console.log( reducer(0, null) ); // should output -> 0
```

**ERROR**

```
    TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
01-identity-reducer.ts (10,5): Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'reducer'. (2451)
    at getOutput (/Users/person/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:258:17)
    at /Users/person/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:267:16
    at Object.compile (/Users/person/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:403:17)
    at loader (/Users/person/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:289:33)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/person/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:306:14)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/person/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/_bin.ts:179:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'reducer' from the tsc and I'm not sure why

If you don't have a root level import or export in your file then it is considered a *global module*. There is clearly another file that is *also* global and has the variable `reducer` declared.

## Fix

Move to modules (commonjs is a great choice). Alternatively change `let` to `var` and that should give you an error at the location where another `reducer` is declared.

PS: [And IDE can give a much nicer experience here giving you the other variable declaration locations upfront](http://alm.tools/).

Answer (score 1):

Just export a namespace around it.
`export namespace WhatYouLike { ...code... }`